# Django models.field baseado em outro field de outro model

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework

Tenho 2 models Pedidos e Pratos:

É possível fazer um field que seja interligado com outro field de varios outros models?

O model Prato:

```py
Prato(models.Model):
   nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   info = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   valor = models.IntegerField()
```

o modelo Pedido:

```py
Pedido(models.Model):
   Pratos = models.ManyToManyField(Prato)
   valor_total = ## aqui seja o valor total juntando o valor de todos os Pratos
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-PT! Para que outros usuários possam te ajudar com mais facilidade, recomendo que você leia [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para ter umas dicas de como fazer uma boa pergunta.

Comment: Fiquei meio perdido na pergunta, mas pode ser feito herança.. em uma classe específicar partes que pode  sere  amplas o bastante para reutilizar em outros model.

Comment: Acho que um jeito mais fácil de alcançar o seu objetivo — se é que eu entendi corretamente — seria criando um método `def obter_valor_total(self)` dentro do modelo `Pedido` e realizando a operação por ali (p.ex. `sum(prato.valor for prato in self.Pratos.all())`).

Comment: quando eu tento usar isso, aparece ValueError: "<Pedido:>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Comment: A exceção já diz do que se trata o erro: se o objeto instanciado do modelo `Pedido` ainda não tiver um `id` persistente — isto é, ainda não foi salvo (`models.Model.save()`) — não é possível usar o relacionamento *Many-To-Many* `Pratos`.